# NLog and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nlog

I am trying unsuccessfully to use NLog with Visual Studio 2010. However, it works fine with Visual Studio 2008 using the same .config file and the same source code, so what am I doing wrong? Does anybody knows if it is possible to use NLog with VS2010 or if there is any other tool for logging in VS2010?

Comment: Sorry...  I made the corrections

Comment: Looks better but I have another question for you--are you getting error messages when you try to compile a project or is there an error/exception when your program is running?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions it only executes and it doesn't create the Log

Comment: Two things I can think of. Are you sure your config is being read? Are you logging NLog exceptions? i.e. something like this  <nlog throwExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog.log" in your configuration? Does this tell you anything?

Comment: Now im having an issue using NLog with WebServices, i tried with other logging frameworks and it doesnt work on webservices..

Answer (score 1):

I use NLog with VS2010 and Visual Studio 11 Beta without any issues.

Did you upgrade your project to a new/different version of the .NET framework when you first opened the vs2008 solution in VS2010?

If your project is C# then right-click on the project in the solution explorer in VS2010 and check the value for Target Framework in the Application tab. If it is **.NET Framework 4** then it has been changed from what you were previously using.

You might want to try switching it back to whatever you were using before (2.0 or 3.5 most likely)

Comment: I've tried configuring to 3.5 and 4.0 on visual studio 2010 and I still dont get any difference.. I dont know which version of NLog do you have? the issue is that  VS2010 doesnt throw any exception or error message it simply doesnt create the log